# Unit Test with Express, TypeScript, Prisma and Jest

Tags: express, unit-testing, jestjs, prisma

I'm trying to unit test with Prisma and Jest following this link https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/testing/unit-testing.
Here is my test code:

```
test("should create a user ", async () => {   
    var user: any = {
    store_id: "601d6dea-9b89-4c0d-adfc-6ed52424a2a0",
    password: '1234',
    user_name: "username",
    first_name: "Rich",
    last_name: "hello@prisma.io",
    phone: "12345",
    is_phone_verified: true,
    is_email_verified: true,   };

  prismaMock.sec_user_fs.create.mockImplementation(user)

  await expect(createUser(user)).resolves.toEqual({
    store_id: "601d6dea-9b89-4c0d-adfc-6ed52424a2a0"   }); });
```

createUser method is save data to database. Here is code:

```
export async function createUser(user: CreateUser) {
  
    user = await prisma.sec_user_fs.create({
      data: user,
    })

    return {"store_id": user.store_id} }
```

So my questions are:

1. prismaMock.sec_user_fs.create.mockImplementation(user) - In my understanding this line mocked database table, it prevent not insert data to table while testing. But, it does. How can mock without inserting, updating,deleting to table?
2. createUser method return json object. But if i test my api end point /code is below/ how expect result? Because it does return res.status(200) etc.?

```
export default asyncHandler(async (req: CustomRequest, res: Response)=> {

  const body = {
    user_name: req.body.user_name,
    first_name: req.body.first_name,
    last_name: req.body.last_name,
    phone: req.body.phone,
    phone_country_code: req.body.phone_country_code   }

  const user_id = req.params.id

  const user = await prisma.sec_user_fs.updateMany({
    where: {
      user_id,
      status: 'A'
    },
    data: body   });

  res.status(200).send({
    status: 'Success',
    message: req.t('success'),
    errors: [],
    data: user,   }); });
```

Thanks in advance :)